# Change CNN to LSTM keras tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a CNN and like to change this to a LSTM, but when I modified my code I receive the same error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

I already change ndim but didn't work.

follow my cnn

```
def build_model(X,Y,nb_classes):
    nb_filters = 32  # number of convolutional filters to use
    pool_size = (2, 2)  # size of pooling area for max pooling
    kernel_size = (3, 3)  # convolution kernel size
    nb_layers = 4
    input_shape = (1, X.shape[2], X.shape[3])

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1],
                        border_mode='valid', input_shape=input_shape))

    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    for layer in range(nb_layers-1):
        model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1))
        model.add(ELU(alpha=1.0))  
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))
    return model
```

and follow how i like to did my LSTM

```
data_dim = 41
timesteps = 20
num_classes = 10

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(LSTM(64))  
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

What I was doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: your LSTM Code works fine. The problem may be on ur training data shape. Can you print the shape of your training data. `X.shape and Y.shape`

Answer (score 2):

The LSTM code is fine, it executes with no errors for me.
The error you are seeing is related to internal incompatibility of the tensors within the model itself, not related to training data, in which case you'll get an "Exception: Invalid input shape"

What's confusing in your error is that it refers to a GRU layer, which isn't contained anywhere in your model definition. If your model only contains LSTM, you should get an error that calls out the LSTM layer that it conflicts with.

Perhaps check

```
model.get_config()
```

and make sure all the layers and configs are what you intended.
In particular, the first layer should say this:

```
batch_input_shape': (None, 20, 41)
```

Comment: It wont work if the data OP is using is 4d, which it would be for `Convolution2d()`